# Draw line with min-max region with colour intensity at spot according to amount of lines passing through that spot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have N (in my case N>8000) realisations of a random process. These are my value function approximations. These are identical in length vectors of length M. As a result I have a NxM matrix. I know how to plot lines of mean, max and min value at each m \in M. As a result I have a plot of three lines. Maximum value, mean value and minimum value at each m \in M.

Here comes my question. I would like to take my graph one step further. I would like to have sort of a funnel (between min and max values) with a strong line indicating mean value. Furthermore, I would like the funnel to be coloured between min and max values. The colour intensity at a given spot I would like to be proportional to number of curves from my set of N passing through that spot.

I have been searching internet for "advanced plot designs" but never found anything of that sort. I found funnel with uniform colouring (see attached picture)[image: funnel wit uniform colouring] but that is of no interest to me. I also do not really know how to properly describe the plot in "keywords" in order to be able to search for it well.

I would appreciate any help that could push me towards finding a solution!

Comment: Does plotting all curves transparent give you what you want?

Comment: @MihaiAndrei Dear Sir, You are a star! Maybe it is not ideal, but it is 95% good enough, and takes 2 mins to implement. Thank You very much!